# When changing input type="file" button to image affecting parent() and prev()

Tags: jquery

I have the following html. I am using a fonts awesome icon to replace the input file.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <i class="fa fa-times pointer socialmedia_image_remove" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none"></i>
    <img class="img-responsive img-rounded socialmedia_image" src="" style="max-width: 100px; border: solid 1px lightgrey; display: none">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload"><i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
        <input id="file-upload" type="file" class="form-control add_image_new">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <i class="fa fa-times pointer socialmedia_image_remove" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none"></i>
    <img class="img-responsive img-rounded socialmedia_image" src="" style="max-width: 100px; border: solid 1px lightgrey; display: none">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload"><i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
        <input id="file-upload" type="file" class="form-control add_image_new">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Then in my **JQUERY** I am capturing the event like so

```
function readURLNew(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $(input).parent().prev().attr('src', e.target.result);
            $(input).parent().prev().prev().show();
            $(input).parent().prev().show();
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
$(document).on('change','.add_image_new', function() {
    readURLNew(this);
});
```

Which is supposed to add the new url to the `src` of the `img` that it is next to and display some tags that are set to `display: none`

What is happening is that <s>the appropriate `parent` and `prev` are not properly finding the elements they need to display which are</s> when I try and select an image on the bottom `form-group` it will populate the image on the top `form-group` instead of the bottom one.

Here is a **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/n4gyj303/1/)** to show you whats going on thanks to @choz. If you select the image on the bottom button it places it on top of the top button.

<s>If I remove this</s>

<s>It works fine.</s>

<s>Since I am using `parent()` first regardless the order backwards is still the same whether I start from `<input>` or `<label>`</s>

<s>I have a feeling that the use of associating the `for="file-upload"` to the input file is effecting the order of the tags. I am not sure how to fix this.</s>

Comment: Did you cache the input as a variable named input? Otherwise, the issue is that you need to include `input` in quotes. For example, `$('input').parent().prev().show();`.

Comment: Hmm. What about looking for them a different way? `$(this).closest('.form-group').find('img')...` If that doesn't work, not sure I personally know the answer.

Comment: actually the first `form-group` wouldn't work because I need to start at the second one up. I even tried `parent().closest('.form-group')` and that didn't work. Im scratching my head on this one.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't read the classes closely enough. Perhaps there is a higher-level wrapper you could skip up to and work your way back down? Point being just that if single-element traversal with `.parent()` and `.prev()` is troublesome, maybe you could use another method to skip several elements up to something that's definitely not affected and then work back down the tree. You could play with it. Others may have a better answer for the underlying problem for you, but I don't. Sorry!

Comment: `.prev` is supposed to work with element the same type (at least this what I understood from the docs) why you don't use like `var img = $(this).parent().parent().find('img');` `img.attr('src', e.target.result);` `$(this).parent().parent().find('i.fa-times').show();` `img.show();`

Comment: @ElmerDantas I tried that as well and didnt work, but if I remove the `<label>` it still works. I have edited my question and added all my code maybe that would help.

Comment: Works good for me [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4gyj303/). It finds the `parent()` and its `prev()`s well. What's the issue again?

Comment: Ok found out it was working, but not correctly. I edited my question again to show you whats going on. i have multiple `form-groups` going on and I think the function is not able to determine its current location so that `parent()` and `prev()` can grab the correct tags next to it. Instead its going to to first one on top.