# Preserving "this" location when passing into function and using parent() and prev()

Tags: jquery

I have some dynamic data that is repeated and in order to execute my results I have to find the neighboring elements with things like `parent()` and `prev()`. I had a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44733615/when-changing-input-type-file-button-to-image-affecting-parent-and-prev) that remained unanswered that originally had nothing to do with this question, but I discovered it does and the issue I am having is when I am passing `this` into a function the `parent()` and `prev()` are not finding the correct location because I do not believe that `this` is being preserved.

What is happening here below is when I select an image with the input it renders the image above the current input that selected it. Instead it always renders the image above the first input.

Here is a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/n4gyj303/1/) to show what is happening.

What I need is the image to appear above the input that I am selecting and not just go to the top. Hope that makes sense.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <i class="fa fa-times pointer socialmedia_image_remove" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none"></i>
    <img class="img-responsive img-rounded socialmedia_image" src="" style="max-width: 100px; border: solid 1px lightgrey; display: none">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload"><i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
        <input id="file-upload" type="file" class="form-control add_image_new">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <i class="fa fa-times pointer socialmedia_image_remove" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none"></i>
    <img class="img-responsive img-rounded socialmedia_image" src="" style="max-width: 100px; border: solid 1px lightgrey; display: none">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload"><i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
        <input id="file-upload" type="file" class="form-control add_image_new">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
function readURLNew(input) {
    this.input = input;
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            debugger;
            $(input).parent().prev().attr('src', e.target.result);
            $(input).parent().prev().prev().show();
            $(input).parent().prev().show();
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
$(function() {
    $(document).on('change','.add_image_new', function() {
        readURLNew(this);
    });
})
```

Comment: ID's are unique, and can be only used once in the current document. Just change your ID's and `for` attributes so you're not using duplicate ID's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact you are using the same ID for your inputs is what's causing your problem. Both your labels are pointing to the same input, via their `for` attributes. Change the IDs of the input to be unique. Then change the `for` attributes of your labels accordingly.

Here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4gyj303/2/)

Comment: yeah I feel like an idiot I didn't even notice I did that and I know better. That fixed it guys thanks so much

Comment: I do that too so no problem. :)